# _universalCookie.Cookies is not a constructor error in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, cookies

How to use universal-cookie in ReactJS? I'm getting this error "_universalCookie.Cookies is not a constructor".

```
import { Cookies } from 'universal-cookie';
...
     const cookies = new Cookies();
           cookies.set('myTokenCookies', 'response.data.token', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
           console.log(cookies.get('myTokenCookies'));
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do

```
import * as Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
```

to fix this. I chose to ditch universal-cookie and use the detect-browser package instead.

Answer (score 3):

You need to import Cookies as a default export:

```
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
```

and not

```
import { Cookies } from 'universal-cookie';
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you're missing an import:

```
import Cookies from "universal-cookie/es6/Cookies"
```

It looks like other's have had this issue: [source](https://github.com/bendotcodes/cookies/issues/186)